# multiple fetch requests using List ( 6 times after compiling, multiple while scrolling )

Tags: reactjs

im new to react and im building an app where i encountered this problem, i have a component that fetches data and displays it in a list ,but on the page, it fetches multiple times each time i scroll the list.`

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import ListItem from '@mui/material/ListItem';
import ListItemButton from '@mui/material/ListItemButton';
import { FixedSizeList} from 'react-window';
import ListItemText from '@mui/material/ListItemText';
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
const JobsListData = (props) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  var { index, style } = props;
  const url = 'http://localhost:5000/api/v1/jobs'
  const [jobsList,setJobs] = useState(null)
  const jobsfunction = async () => {
    try{
          const data = await axios.get(url)
          .then(response => {
              setJobs(response.data)
          })
    }catch(e){
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
  useEffect(()=>{
    jobsfunction();
  },[]);
    if(jobsList){
      const maxlength = jobsList.total_results;
    if(index<maxlength){return (
      <ListItem key={index} component="div" disablePadding>
        <ListItem > 
        <p><h3>{jobsList.jobs[index].name}</h3><br></br>
        <b>Payrate</b> :{jobsList.jobs[index].payrate}<br></br>
        <b>Adress</b> :{jobsList.jobs[index].adress}<br></br>
        <b>Job ID</b> :{jobsList.jobs[index]._id}</p>
        </ListItem>
      </ListItem>
    );}}
    return ([])
}

function VirtualizedList() {
  return (
    <div className='VirtualizedList' id='VirtualizedList'>
        <div className='container'>
            <div className='col-2'>
                <Box
                 sx={{ width: '100%', height: 400, maxWidth: 360, bgcolor: 'background.paper' }}
                >
                <FixedSizeList
                height={400}
                width={650}
                itemSize={100}
                itemCount={200}
                >
                {JobsListData}
                </FixedSizeList>
                </Box>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
  );
}
export default VirtualizedList;
`
```

when i remove the FixedSizeList the fetch request happens only once but when it is there, it fetches (6 times to be exact) in the beginning except for the scroll thing.

this problem causes the list to glitch out and sometimes disappear

Answer (score 1):

try to fetch the data in the parent component

Something like that:

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import ListItem from '@mui/material/ListItem';
import ListItemButton from '@mui/material/ListItemButton';
import { FixedSizeList} from 'react-window';
import ListItemText from '@mui/material/ListItemText';
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const JobsListData = (props) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  var { index, style, jobsList } = props;
 
    if(jobsList){
      const maxlength = jobsList.total_results;
    if(index<maxlength){return (
      <ListItem key={index} component="div" disablePadding>
        <ListItem > 
        <p><h3>{jobsList.jobs[index].name}</h3><br></br>
        <b>Payrate</b> :{jobsList.jobs[index].payrate}<br></br>
        <b>Adress</b> :{jobsList.jobs[index].adress}<br></br>
        <b>Job ID</b> :{jobsList.jobs[index]._id}</p>
        </ListItem>
      </ListItem>
    );}}
    return ([])
}

function VirtualizedList() {

 const url = 'http://localhost:5000/api/v1/jobs'
 const [jobsList,setJobs] = useState(null)
 
 const jobsfunction = async () => {
    try{
          const data = await axios.get(url)
          .then(response => {
              setJobs(response.data)
          })
    }catch(e){
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
  
  useEffect(()=>{
    jobsfunction();
  },[]);
  
  return (
    <div className='VirtualizedList' id='VirtualizedList'>
        <div className='container'>
            <div className='col-2'>
                <Box
                 sx={{ width: '100%', height: 400, maxWidth: 360, bgcolor: 'background.paper' }}
                >
                <FixedSizeList
                height={400}
                width={650}
                itemSize={100}
                itemCount={200}
                >
                 <JobsListData jobsList={jobsList}/>
                </FixedSizeList>
                </Box>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
  );
}
export default VirtualizedList;
```